# Available Memory SNMP MIB for post-2016 kernel/CentOS 7+?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, snmp, net-snmp

It looks like the "MemAvailReal" actually only reports free memory, not available memory. Is there a more recent version of this MIB or a different standard MIB which measures available memory?

I tried this from a CentOS 7.3 system with the following packages, but pretty sure this is the same behavior in  the most recent point releases as well.

- net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.x86_64
- net-snmp-utils-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.x86_64
- net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.x86_64
- net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.x86_64

Example of behavior:

[root@hostname ~]# free -m
              **total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available**
Mem:           7823         232        4183         156        3407        7097
Swap:          2047          12        2035

There is ~7.0 GB of available memory, however...

[root@hostname ~]# snmpwalk -v 2c -c communitystring 127.0.0.1 memAvailReal
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal.0 = INTEGER: 4294500 kB

The "memAvailReal" MIB seems to report the free memory.

Comment: 7.3 is incredibly old. Please retry with 7.6 and see wether there is a difference. The recent version is 5.7.2-37 which might have changed things.

Comment: The highest I can go right now without going out of my way is 7.5 - which has 5.7.2-32, and I can see that that has the same behavior. The kernel has had the same behavior with displaying available memory since 7.1 at a minimum as far as I know. Unless there is a new MIB I am not aware of.

Comment: The value of `memAvailReal` matches the third column (4183). If you want something matching the first column (7823), please read `memTotalReal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per net-snmp-libs version: 5.7.2-43 `memAvailReal` now returns the available memory instead of the free memory. This package should be available in RHEL/CentOS 7.7

More information:
https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2019:2239
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1250060

**Update:** This change was reverted: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1779609 & https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/code/ci/ef6db67f708f6590fb9d2797022ca1d957c89073